# Display quota usage in horde5

Tags: quota, horde, imp

i thought this should be a piece of cake, displaying the quota usage in horde webmail (IMP).

I have found several guidelines on the web - but no one seems to work in the latest version of horde. The last configuration i tried was this in /imp/config/backends.php:

```
quota' => array(
    'driver' => 'courier',
    'params' => array()
)

$servers['imap'] = array(
    'name' => 'IMAP Server',
    'server' => 'localhost',
    'hordeauth' => 'full',
    'protocol' => 'imap/notls',
    'port' => 143,
    'maildomain' => getenv("DNS"),
    'smtphost' => 'localhost',
    'smtpport' => 25,
    'realm' => '',
    'preferred' => '',
    'dotfiles' => false,
    'hierarchies' => array(),
    'quota' => array(
        'driver' => 'courier',
        'params' => array()
    ),
```

But - it's not working at all.. i can imagine that the implementation was changed completely for horde5, but i can't find helps and guidelines for horde5.

Maybe anyone out there has already solved this problem?
)

Comment: I tried several configurations, too, but no quota is being displayed. I got no error messages, but the '$("quota-text")' span is always empty. Any ideas, anyone? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own imap server in /imp/config/backends.local.php :

```
$servers['yourimap'] = array(
    'disabled' => false,
[...]
    'quota' => array(
        'driver' => 'imap',
        'params' => array(
            'hide_when_unlimited' => true,
            'unit' => 'MB'
        )
    ),
[...]
);
```

You can find documentation in /imp/config/backends.php

Quota driver depends on your IMAP server. Generally works with driver 'imap' who used IMAP QUOTA extension to handle quotas.

Regards